# NASM ReadConsoleA or WriteConsoleA Buffer Debugging Issue

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I am writing a NASM Assembly program on Windows to get the user to enter in two single digit numbers, add these together and then output the result. I am trying to use the Windows API for input and output.

Unfortunately, whilst I can get it to read in one number as soon as the program loops round to get the second the program ends rather than asking for the second value.

The output of the program shown below:

[image]

What is interesting is that if I input `1` then the value displayed is one larger so it is adding to something!

[image]

This holds for other single digits (`2-9`) entered as well.

I am pretty sure it is related to how I am using the `ReadConsoleA` function but I have hit a bit of a wall attempting to find a solution. I have installed **gdb** to debug the program and assembled it as follows:

- `nasm -f win64 -g -o task9.obj task9.asm`
- `GoLink /console /entry _main task9.obj kernel32.dll`
- `gdb task9`

[image]

But I just get the following error:

- `"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop/task9.exe": not in executable format: File format not recognized`

I have since read that NASM doesn't output the debug information needed for the Win64 format but I am not 100% sure about that. I am fairly sure I have the 64-bit version of GDB installed:

[image]

My program is as follows:

```
extern ExitProcess                          ;windows API function to exit process
extern WriteConsoleA                        ;windows API function to write to the console window (ANSI version)
extern ReadConsoleA                         ;windows API function to read from the console window (ANSI version)
extern GetStdHandle                         ;windows API to get the for the console handle for input/output

section .data                               ;the .data section is where variables and constants are defined

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE   equ -11
STD_INPUT_HANDLE    equ -10

digits      db      '0123456789'            ;list of digits

input_message db   'Please enter your next number: '
length equ $-input_message

section .bss                                ;the .bss section is where space is reserved for additional variables

input_buffer:   resb 2                      ;reserve 64 bits for user input

char_written:   resb    4
chars:   resb 1                             ;reversed for use with write operation

section .text                               ;the .text section is where the program code goes

global _main                                ;tells the machine which label to start program execution from

_num_to_str:
        cmp rax, 0                          ;compare value in rax to 0
        jne .convert                        ;if not equal then jump to label
        jmp .output

.convert:
        ;get next digit value
        inc r15                             ;increment the counter for next digit

        mov rcx, 10
        xor rdx, rdx                        ;clear previous remainder result
        div rcx                             ;divide value in rax by value in rcx
                                            ;quotient (result) stored in rax
                                            ;remainder stored in rdx

        push rdx                            ;store remainder on the stack

        jmp _num_to_str

.output:
        pop rdx                             ;get the last digit from the stack

        ;convert digit value to ascii character
        mov r10, digits                     ;load the address of the digits into rsi
        add r10, rdx                        ;get the character of the digits string to display

        mov rdx, r10                        ;digit to print
        mov r8, 1                           ;one byte to be output

        call _print

        ;decide whether to loop
        dec r15                             ;reduce remaining digits (having printed one)
        cmp r15, 0                          ;are there digits left to print?
        jne .output                          ;if not equal then jump to label output

        ret

_print:
        ;get the output handle
        mov rcx, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE          ;specifies that the output handle is required
        call GetStdHandle                   ;returns value for handle to rax

        mov rcx, rax
        mov r9, char_written

        call WriteConsoleA

        ret

_read:
        ;get the input handle
        mov rcx, STD_INPUT_HANDLE           ;specifies that the input handle is required
        call GetStdHandle

        ;get value from keyboard
        mov rcx, rax                        ;place the handle for operation

        mov rdx, input_buffer               ;set name to receive input from keyboard

        mov r8, 2                           ;max number of characters to read
        mov r9, chars                       ;stores the number of characters actually read

        call ReadConsoleA


        movzx r12, byte[input_buffer]

        ret

_get_value:
        mov rdx, input_message              ;move the input message into rdx for function call
        mov r8, length                      ;load the length of the message for function call

        call _print
        xor r8, r8
        xor r9, r9
        call _read
.end:
        ret

_main:
        mov r13, 0                          ;counter for values input
        mov r14, 0                          ;total for calculation
.loop:
        xor r12, r12
        call _get_value                     ;get value from user

        sub r12, '0'                        ;convert char to integer
        add r14, r12                        ;add value to total

        ;decide whether to loop for another character or not
        inc r13
        cmp r13, 2
        jne .loop

        ;convert total to ASCII value

        mov rax, r14                             ;num_to_str expects total in rax

        mov r15, 0                               ;num_to_str uses r15 as a counter - must be initialised
        call _num_to_str

        ;exit the program
        mov rcx, 0                          ;exit code
        call ExitProcess
```

I would really appreciate any assistance you can offer either with resolving the issue or how to resolve the issue with gdb.

Comment: You probably installed the 32 bit gdb.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I have the 64-bit version installed:

Comment: Yeah, your screenshot looks fine. _Unless you have switched off command line reports using the /ni or /no switch GoLink will tell you in which format it has produced the executable._ ... can you check what the linker said?

Comment: I have actually managed to get the debugger to run by downloading another version from [here](http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=gdb) but it doesn't find any symbols in the code and even when I set a breakpoint based on an address from advice in [this question](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1935/how-to-handle-stripped-binaries-with-gdb-no-source-no-symbols-and-gdb-only-sho) I can't step through the code. I just get a `can't find bounds of current function` error.

Comment: I just ran `nasm -f win64 -y` to see what debug formats it supports at it is `null`. This is likewise true of **win32**, **macho32** and **macho64**, which is pretty painful - looks like **elf32/64** is the only supported debug format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following issues with your code:

1. [Microsoft x86-64 convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kcdt6fy.aspx) mandates `rsp` be 16 byte aligned.
2. You must reserve space for the arguments on the stack, even if you pass them in registers.
3. Your `chars` variable needs 4 bytes not 1.
4. `ReadConsole` expects 5 arguments.
5. You should read 3 bytes because `ReadConsole` returns `CR LF`. Or you could just ignore leading whitespace.
6. Your `_num_to_str` is broken if the input is `0`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions...I hadn't really clocked **just** how important the stack alignment was when calling functions. I have included the final program. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on **Jester's** suggestions this is the final program:

```
extern ExitProcess                          ;windows API function to exit process
extern WriteConsoleA                        ;windows API function to write to the console window (ANSI version)
extern ReadConsoleA                         ;windows API function to read from the console window (ANSI version)
extern GetStdHandle                         ;windows API to get the for the console handle for input/output

section .data                               ;the .data section is where variables and constants are defined

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE   equ -11
STD_INPUT_HANDLE    equ -10

digits      db      '0123456789'            ;list of digits

input_message db   'Please enter your next number: '
length equ $-input_message

NULL        equ     0

section .bss                                ;the .bss section is where space is reserved for additional variables

input_buffer:   resb 3                      ;reserve 64 bits for user input

char_written:   resb    4
chars:   resb 4                             ;reversed for use with write operation

section .text                               ;the .text section is where the program code goes

global _main                                ;tells the machine which label to start program execution from

_num_to_str:
        sub rsp, 32
        cmp rax, 0
        jne .next_digit
        push rax
        inc r15
        jmp .output
.next_digit:
        cmp rax, 0                          ;compare value in rax to 0
        jne .convert                        ;if not equal then jump to label
        jmp .output

.convert:
        ;get next digit value
        inc r15                             ;increment the counter for next digit

        mov rcx, 10
        xor rdx, rdx                        ;clear previous remainder result
        div rcx                             ;divide value in rax by value in rcx
                                            ;quotient (result) stored in rax
                                            ;remainder stored in rdx

        sub rsp, 8                          ;add space on stack for value
        push rdx                            ;store remainder on the stack

        jmp .next_digit

.output:
        pop rdx                             ;get the last digit from the stack
        add rsp, 8                          ;remove space from stack for popped value

        ;convert digit value to ascii character
        mov r10, digits                     ;load the address of the digits into rsi
        add r10, rdx                        ;get the character of the digits string to display

        mov rdx, r10                        ;digit to print
        mov r8, 1                           ;one byte to be output

        call _print

        ;decide whether to loop
        dec r15                             ;reduce remaining digits (having printed one)
        cmp r15, 0                          ;are there digits left to print?
        jne .output                          ;if not equal then jump to label output
        add rsp, 32
        ret

_print:
        sub rsp, 40
        ;get the output handle
        mov rcx, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE          ;specifies that the output handle is required
        call GetStdHandle                   ;returns value for handle to rax

        mov rcx, rax
        mov r9, char_written

        mov rax, qword 0                    ;fifth argument
        mov qword [rsp+0x20], rax

        call WriteConsoleA
        add rsp, 40
        ret

_read:
        sub rsp, 40
        ;get the input handle
        mov rcx, STD_INPUT_HANDLE           ;specifies that the input handle is required
        call GetStdHandle

        ;get value from keyboard
        mov rcx, rax                        ;place the handle for operation
        xor rdx, rdx
        mov rdx, input_buffer               ;set name to receive input from keyboard



        mov r8, 3                           ;max number of characters to read
        mov r9, chars                       ;stores the number of characters actually read

        mov rax, qword 0                    ;fifth argument
        mov qword [rsp+0x20], rax

        call ReadConsoleA


        movzx r12, byte[input_buffer]
        add rsp, 40
        ret

_get_value:
        sub rsp, 40

        mov rdx, input_message              ;move the input message into rdx for function call
        mov r8, length                      ;load the length of the message for function call

        call _print
        call _read
.end:
        add rsp, 40
        ret

_main:
        sub rsp, 40
        mov r13, 0                          ;counter for values input
        mov r14, 0                          ;total for calculation
.loop:
        call _get_value                     ;get value from user

        sub r12, '0'                        ;convert char to integer
        add r14, r12                        ;add value to total

        ;decide whether to loop for another character or not
        inc r13
        cmp r13, 2
        jne .loop

        ;convert total to ASCII value

        mov rax, r14                             ;num_to_str expects total in rax

        mov r15, 0                               ;num_to_str uses r15 as a counter - must be initialised
        call _num_to_str

        ;exit the program
        mov rcx, 0                          ;exit code

        call ExitProcess
        add rsp, 40
        ret
```

As it turned out I was actually missing a 5th argument in the `WriteConsole` function as well.

Comment: Note that your `_num_to_str` is still misaligning the stack because it does an undefined amount of pushes. You could simply allocate a fixed buffer for the worst case scenario (a 64 bit number will be at most 20 digits long) and use normal `mov` instructions.

Comment: Could I just do add rsp, 8 before a push and sub rsp, 8 after a pop?

Comment: Ugly will do for tonight ;-) Thanks again!